# Sorting within .map affects the original array instead of returning new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, array.prototype.map

I have a 2d array of numbers: array1. I would like to map over each array within array1 and sort the numbers in each array and return them to a new array: sortedRows. I know that mapping over an array returns a new array, however when I sort each internal array during the mapping process, it sorts all numbers within array1 as well as sortedRows.

I've already tried separately mapping array1 to rows and then map/sorting to sortedRows and I've tried copying with the spread operator (rows = [...array1]). Both attempts get the same result below.

```
let array1 = [[5, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2], 
             [6, 7, 2, 1, 9, 5, 3, 4, 8],
             [1, 9, 8, 3, 4, 2, 5, 6, 7],
             [8, 5, 9, 7, 6, 1, 4, 2, 3],
             [4, 2, 6, 8, 5, 3, 7, 9, 1],
             [7, 1, 3, 9, 2, 4, 8, 5, 6],
             [9, 6, 1, 5, 3, 7, 2, 8, 4],
             [2, 8, 7, 4, 1, 9, 6, 3, 5],
             [3, 4, 5, 2, 8, 6, 1, 7, 9]]

let sortedRows = array1.map(arr => arr.sort((a, b) => a - b))
```

```
console.log(array1)
console.log(sortedRows)
// expected

[ [5, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2], 
  [6, 7, 2, 1, 9, 5, 3, 4, 8],
  [1, 9, 8, 3, 4, 2, 5, 6, 7],
  [8, 5, 9, 7, 6, 1, 4, 2, 3],
  [4, 2, 6, 8, 5, 3, 7, 9, 1],
  [7, 1, 3, 9, 2, 4, 8, 5, 6],
  [9, 6, 1, 5, 3, 7, 2, 8, 4],
  [2, 8, 7, 4, 1, 9, 6, 3, 5],
  [3, 4, 5, 2, 8, 6, 1, 7, 9]]
[ [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ],
  [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ],
  [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ],
  [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ],
  [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ],
  [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ],
  [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ],
  [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ],
  [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ] ]


//actual

[ [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ],
  [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ],
  [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ],
  [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ],
  [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ],
  [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ],
  [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ],
  [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ],
  [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ] ]
[ [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ],
  [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ],
  [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ],
  [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ],
  [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ],
  [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ],
  [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ],
  [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ],
  [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ] ]
```

Answer (score 3):

`.sort` mutates the original array, so when you have

```
array1.map(arr =>
```

the `arr` there refers to the existing sub-array - if you call `.sort` on it, you'll change that sub-array.

Make a copy of the array first instead:

```
const sortedRows = array1.map(arr => arr.slice().sort((a, b) => a - b))
```

```js
let array1 = [[5, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2], 
             [6, 7, 2, 1, 9, 5, 3, 4, 8],
             [1, 9, 8, 3, 4, 2, 5, 6, 7],
             [8, 5, 9, 7, 6, 1, 4, 2, 3],
             [4, 2, 6, 8, 5, 3, 7, 9, 1],
             [7, 1, 3, 9, 2, 4, 8, 5, 6],
             [9, 6, 1, 5, 3, 7, 2, 8, 4],
             [2, 8, 7, 4, 1, 9, 6, 3, 5],
             [3, 4, 5, 2, 8, 6, 1, 7, 9]];

const sortedRows = array1.map(arr => arr.slice().sort((a, b) => a - b));

document.write(array1.join('<br>'));
document.write('<br><br><br>' + sortedRows.join('<br>'));
```

Comment: Great answer. This is a reference I use to check if an array method mutates the original array or not: https://doesitmutate.xyz/

Comment: Excellent. Thank you!